# Как убрать проблему: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library?

Tags: php

> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20151012/' - /usr/lib/php/20151012/: cannot read file data: Is a directory in Unknown on line 0

Comment: вывод `ls -l /usr/lib/php/20151012/` приведите в вопрос

Comment: дубликат: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/576131/178576