# PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library

Tags: php, cron

Приходит на почту ошибка с таким заголовком:

> Cron  [ -x /usr/lib/php/sessionclean ] && /usr/lib/php/sessionclean

и с таким содержимым:

> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20151012/' - /usr/lib/php/20151012/: cannot read file data: Is a directory in Unknown on line 0

Что это может быть и как это исправить?

Comment: Эм-м, просто при выполнении задания из заголовка топика крон получает warning от этого скрипта (?) о чём Вам и сообщает в письме...

Comment: то есть можно игнорировать ошибку? или что то нужно предпринять?)

Comment: Ну-у-у, это зависит от того, что это и нужно ли оно Вам :) Если не ошибаюсь, тут уже это обсуждали, а решать надо оно или нет - Вам :) link: https://www.linux.org.ru/forum/general/12787841 + "workaround": http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36784385/setting-up-php-sessionclean-cron-job-to-run-in-chroot-environment

Comment: дубликат: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/575776/178576

Comment: я не могу туда добавить ничего. я с телефона там писал. можно удалить тот вопрос?

Answer (score 2):

судя по всему, в каком-то из конфигурационных файлов, загружаемых интерпретатором *php* во время запуска (об этом свидетельствует строка `Unknown on line 0`), присутствует строка примерно такого вида (ну, или что-то в этом роде):

```
extension=/usr/lib/php/20151012/
```

узнать точно список интерпретируемых ini-файлов можно, например, с помощью вызова функции `phpinfo()`.

---

чаще всего они «сосредоточены» в районе каталогов `/ect/php*`. можно поискать файл с таким содержимым, например, так:

```
$ grep -r '/usr/lib/php/20151012/' /etc/php*
```

и, найдя, внести необходимые изменения (удалить эту строку или закомментировать).

Comment: а можете мне подсказать пошагово как это сделать? я в Этом Новичок. Ubuntu 16/04 панель Ispmanager