# Ошибка после установки php на сервере

Tags: php, centos, elastix

Поставил php командой yum install -y php, вроде как успешно установилось.
Команда php -version выводит ошибку:
[root@cl ~]# php -version
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib64/php/modules/filter.so' - /usr/lib64/php/modules/filter.so: undefined symbol: pcre_exec in Unknown on line 0
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected end of file in Command line code on line 1

Каким образом разрешить эту проблему? Нагуглить ничего не полуилось.
ось Elastix (centos 5.11)
Хотел обновить php, т.к. стоял по умолчанию 5.1

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/576145/178576

Comment: @alexanderbarakin , хотелось бы получить более емкий ответ. Целевой файл является явно исполнительным. Редакторы не берут его.

Comment: более ёмкий ответ проистекает из ваших слов: «Хотел обновить php». обновлять-то надо не только саму программу, но и подгружаемые ею модули. либо отключите загрузку этого модуля (в чём поможет упомянутая выше ссылка), либо обновите и его тоже.